# Loop through main diagonal (/) as well as the cells underneath it in a 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to loop through a (boolean) 2D array diagonally like this: `/` (not like this `\`, as I already know how to do that) as well as the cells underneath. The objective of the method is to go through and set all the cells on and below the diagonal (in row-major order) to true. So, it will start at the top-left and work it's way down from there, and it doesn't have to touch the bottom-right square.

I have code for it to go along the diagonal, it;s just the part underneath I am having difficulty with. Here's my code for the *diagonal*:

```
    for (int r = 0; r < min; r++)
    {
        colorArray[r][min-r-1+difference] = true;
        gui.update(colorArray);
    }
```

Here's some of my code for the diagonal *and* the cells underneath it.:

```
for (int r = 0; r < min; r++)
    {
        colorArray[r][min-r-1+difference] = true;
        for (int i = r; i < rowLength; i++)
        {
            colorArray[i][r] = true;
            gui.update(colorArray);
        }
    }
```

It outputs this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEaiN.jpg

The output I should look more like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZubI.jpg

This is one of my first posts on here, so if my question needs more clarification and editing, please let me know.

Comment: So all the cells "below" diagonal need to have value true, does that include diagonal itself ?

Comment: @GCP Yeah, so the 2D array is initialized to false, then the code should set the diagonal, as well as the cells below it, to true.

Comment: Check what I posted below and see if that's what you wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`r` iterates over row indexes.
`i` iterates over column indexes.

As the row index goes up, the column index should go down.
Because,
as you go down, you want to paint wider and wider sections.
As wide as `r + 1`.

I think the logic will be easier to understand if the column indexes go from 0 until `r`, and you paint the cells from right to left.

```
int min = Math.min(colorArray.length, colorArray[0].length);

for (int r = 0; r < min; r++) {
    char[] row = colorArray[r + Math.max(0, colorArray.length - min)];
    for (int i = 0; i <= r; i++) {
        row[row.length - 1 - i] = true;
        gui.update(colorArray);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. My only question is what is the `row` used for? Couldn't you just do `colorArray.length` inside the for loop?

Comment: @bill if you mean why I create `char[] row`, it's easier to read than if I inline it inside the nested loop. Note that there is no performance cost for doing this.

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is that (0,0) is the top left corner. So you want to start from (max, 0) the top right corner and do diagonally down left?

try this:

```
// top right corner
int x = colorArray.length - 1;
int y = 0;

while(x >= 0){
    int colHeight = colorArray[x].length;
    for (int i = y; i < colHeight; i++){
        colorArray[x][i] = true;
        gui.update(colorArray);
    }
    x--;
    y++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did:

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        boolean[][] arr = new boolean[4][4];


        // we go from main diagonal and set each element on it to true as well as each element after it
        for (int i = 0, j = arr.length - 1; i < arr.length; i++, j--) {
            for (int k = j; k < arr[i].length; k++) {
                arr[i][k] = true;
            }
        }


        // print out result of changing main diagonal and elements below to true
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.printf("%5b ", arr[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
 }
```

First loop is what's important to you, sit down and try to figure out what happens.

Output:

false false false  **true**

false false  **true  true**

false  **true  true  true**

**true  true  true  true**